# Why does getchar() continue to take characters from a line of input instead of asking for more?

Tags: c

The code below from a book I am using is making me very confused. To start, I have no idea why/how the getchar() function is being used to take the entire string. I understand how if one were to input a string, getchar would then take the first character of that string.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void readLine (char buffer[]);

int main (void) {

    int i;
    char line[81];


    printf("Enter Message: ");
    readLine(line);
    printf ("%s\n\n", line); 

    return 0;
}

void readLine (char buffer[]) 
{
    char character;
    int i=0;

    do {
        character = getchar (); 
        buffer[i] = character; 
        ++i;
    }
    while ( character != '\n' );
    buffer[i - 1] = '\0'; 
}
```

For example, I would think that if I entered "this is a test", then the getchar function would take the t and put it into the character variable and then put that into buffer[0]. Im confused how it picks up the "his is a test" because there is nothing to increment which character to take next.

Also a side note, I am confused what is being used as the formal declaration in buffer[] because there was nothing in line. Why was this line included?

I'm sorry if its hard for you to understand what I'm asking because it is very hard to put what I am seeing into words

Comment: "getchar" means "read a character out of the input buffer". not "wait for a keypress"

Comment: "Also a side note, I am confused what is being used as the formal declaration in buffer[] because there was nothing in line. Why was this line included?" - which line are you referring to?

Comment: the char line variable is never initiated and then it is passed to the next function. what is the point of them @artm

Answer (score 0):

> Im confused how it picks up the "his is a test" because there is nothing to increment which character to take next.

That's what your `do - while` loop does. `getchar()` task is to take one character at at time. You then assign that input char to `buffer[i]`, and **increment** `i`. The loop terminates when you enter '\n`.

> Also a side note, I am confused what is being used as the formal declaration in buffer[] because there was nothing in line. Why was this line included?

`char line[81];` should be initialized as `char line[81] = "";`

`line` is then used as a *parameter* to be parsed to function `readLine()`. Now it replaces the formal parameter `buffer`, and all changes you make inside that function to `buffer` are in fact changes you make to `line`. That's basically what happens when you passing a character array to a function.

Comment: so once the character is read out of a buffer, the next getchar call automatically moves to the next unread character?

Comment: Yes `do - while` loop means you keep doing what inside it until the condition becomes `false`.

Comment: ok but I'm still confused on how if I enter a string when it does get char, if only one character gets put into a char variable, how are the other letters still accessed

Comment: @yasgur99, could you explain that question a little more? I'm not sure what you are asking in your comment. `getchar()` is just pulling each character from the input stream (STDIN) and then assigning those char values to the `character` variable. The value of the `character` is then put at the current position in the buffer and this goes on-and-on until the character read in is a newline/line-break character.

Comment: @SpencerDoak I think I understand what getchar() is doing and how it is putting each character into the buffer, but I'm confused why there is a formal declaration for the buffer even though what's being passed to it is empty

Comment: @yasgur99 "but I'm confused why there is a formal declaration for the buffer even though what's being passed to it is empty" - did you check the updated answer? we always need to declare (and initialize) a variable before passing it to a function.

Comment: I understand that but I just don't see the intention of the author. why would we use a formal declaration instead of just making it void and creating the variable in the function

Comment: @yasgur99 - the author is **correct**; if you create a variable inside the function, the scope of that variable is only within that function, how do you then expect that variable to have any value in `main`? that's fundamental of using a function.

Comment: artm, I think @yasgur99 is asking why the buffer isn't just created in `readLine()` and then **returned** to `main`. OP, if `char buffer[81]` was declared in `readLine()`, you would not be able to return it to `main`. In C and C++, an array is just a space allocated in the memory to store some predefined number values. The variable that is actually just a pointer to the first element in the array (e.g., `buffer` is just a pointer to the first character in the array). If you returned the pointer to `main`, `main` would get the *"location"* of the array, however, the array would be out of scope.